# How can I silently upgrade M1 macOS?

Tags: macos, monterey, apple-silicon

I want to upgrade macOS silently without a password (I'm running with administrative privileges)

I'm trying to run the following command on M1 mac (which works on Mac with intel chip)

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --agreetolicense –nointeraction --forcequitapps
```

and I got the following error:

> Error: failed to authorize for installation. Provide a password with
> --stdinpass or --passprompt.

I know I can use `--stdinpass` or `--passprompt`:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --agreetolicense --forcequitapps --passprompt
```

but I want to install without password like I did on Mac Intel.

How can I make it work? or is there another way to silently install macOS patch?

Comment: Let's start from the beginning, why do you want to upgrade an OS 'silently'? Why don't you want to input a password? Do you not know your admin password? An OS upgrade is not the sort of thing you want to do in an ad-hoc manner. You want to prepare for it with a backup, and a tested recovery method. All of that requires planning and forethought, and some degree of hands-on involvement in the process. And certainly involves entering a password. This advice is regardless of whatever you were allowed to do in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't relate to your question, but you have a different typo in your line:

`sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --agreetolicense –nointeraction --forcequitapps`

`–nointeraction`  only has one hyphen. My policy was erroring out because I just copied and pasted yours. I just needed to add another hyphen there.